# What if I want to analyze a time series, but the period is not constant?

Tags: python, time, time-series, correlation

What if I want to analyze a time series, but the period is not constant?
for example :

> 1th period : 34 s
> 2th period : 33 s
> 3th period : 35 s
> 4th period : 34 s

In this situation, how can we prove that there is a cycle for each period?

Comment: Hi, could you provide a bit more context around the task you are trying to solve ? It would help us to guide you toward methods adapted to the task and data type (numerical, categorical, ...).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.